# В чем разница между vue init webpack / webpack-simple / create?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Всем привет, кто-нибудь может объяснить для чего во vue разные команды инициализации проекта, vue init webpack / webpack-simple / create.
Как я понял это создание проекта, но с разной структурой и меня интересует какая для каких случаев нужна? В доках vue cli ничего не сказано

Comment: это всего лишь разница версий vue-cli,
самая последняя версия через create

Comment: Ааа, понял, спасибо.